# Is there a way to disable Excel's "Include new rows and columns in table" for one file?

Tags: excel, vba

I know this auto-include setting can be turned off globally via
`File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options... > AutoFormat As You Type`.

[image: autoformat as you type]

Is it possible to change this setting for a single file?

If not a setting, is there a clever VBA solution to stop if from happening?

Comment: Maybe an undo when catching the event that fires it? See my code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/235449/197645) it's still a WIP though...

Answer (score 0):

The property that you want to toggle is `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange`.

If you want only want to turn off "include new rows/columns in table" for one sheet, you can put this code into the **Sheet's module**

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I was super excited but it doesn't seem to work. Strangely... the setting I posted doesn't work either. With either of them my tables continue to auto-expand when I hit `tab` while on the last cell of the table. Strange. ‍♀️ _(using Office 365 (16.12228.20322 64-bit)_

Comment: It seems like you're right, hitting `tab` while working in a table will just jump down to a new row in the table regardless of the setting I mentioned above. Not sure that there's a setting available to us to prevent it from doing this, sorry. The setting that I changed does seem to prevent it from grabbing adjacent values into the table, though, so there's that...